# LibGDX on Netbeans and Android

Tags: android, netbeans, libgdx

I am trying to run my application that uses LibGDX on Andriod using the NetBeans IDE.
However the game crashes for some reason, I just got the "This application have stopped to work" message when I try to run the application. Everything works great on PC, so apparently I have missed something in the andriod set up. Setting up an andriod project on NetBeans is not an documented area and things seem to be different on Eclipse.

If someone have manged to run LibGDX on andriod by setting up the project in Netbeans, please share the steps you did.

Some code, I doubt that would help through:

```
public class Game extends AndroidApplication {
    public void onCreate (android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            initialize((ApplicationListener) new game.GameSystem(new Size2i(100, 100)), false);
    }
}
```

The debug output I get is the following:

```
D/dalvikvm(  478): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.RPGGame/lib/libgdx.so 0x40515708
D/dalvikvm(  478): Added shared lib /data/data/com.RPGGame/lib/libgdx.so 0x40515708
D/dalvikvm(  478): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.RPGGame/lib/libgdx.so 0x40515708, skipping init
D/AndroidRuntime(  478): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  478): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.RPGGame/com.RPGGame.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: game.GameSystem
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: game.GameSystem
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at com.RPGGame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
E/AndroidRuntime(  478):    ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(  104):   Force finishing activity com.RPGGame/.MainActivity
W/ActivityManager(  104): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40512238 com.RPGGame/.MainActivity}
D/dalvikvm(  408): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 54% free 2537K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 102ms
W/ActivityManager(  104): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40512238 com.RPGGame/.MainActivity}
D/dalvikvm(  420): GC_EXPLICIT freed 324K, 55% free 2532K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 183ms
D/dalvikvm(  322): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 55% free 2589K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 72ms
```

So basically I cannot cast game.GameSystem to ApplicationListener. Even if GameSystem implements ApplicationListener.

GameSystem works as intended on PC, all I did for the Andriod project was to put that code in the main file.

Comment: You should be able to get more informative logs (ideally a backtrace) from Android.  Either use adb or Logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it now, turned out I used the wrong version of game.GameSystem.